# SQLite - openDatabase crashes on 4.0.3 - no such table android_metadata

Tags: android-sqlite

I have a app that is using a prepopulated database - following the instructions from here:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

The app is working fine on Android 4.1, 4.3, 5.0, 5.1 - however on 4.0.3 and 4.0 it crashes with

```
E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(551): SELECT locale FROM android_metadata failed
E/SQLiteDatabase(551): Failed to open the database. closing it.
E/SQLiteDatabase(551): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: android_metadata
```

I've double checked and the metadata table has been created on the database as per the article.

The error is being generated from:

```
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

I've read similar threads and guys have got around this error using SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS if they did not have the android_metadata table created.

I have tried the above - same error.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/org.example/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "model_paint_conversion.db";
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Have also tried removing the path - I then get a error copying the database.

Any idea what it crashes on 4.0 and 4.0.3 but works on the other versions?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging around - viewed the db file that is copied to the emulator and found the metadata table was indeed missing. Very odd - I def created it.

Now recreated it and its working.

Answer (score 0):

try `SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS` with `SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY` and add uses permission for `WRITE_SETTINGS` in manifest.
I had a same problem and I did like this and worked for me...